# Troublesome package creating

Tags: r

I have some problems with creating package, can you please spot my mistake?

I followed instruction below :

1.Create functions I want in my package

2.Open new project -> R package

3.Create as many R documentation as many functions I implemented, and then put them into man folder

4.Press Ctr+Shift+B to install package.

The warning I'm facing is

Warning: C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.3/library/mypackage/man/myfun2.Rd:62: All text must be in a section

I search internet about solution to that problem but I found only involved instructions containing other approach. Is there possibility how to fix this ? Or other approach with using other packages is crucial (as roxygen).

Thanks in advance

Comment: What IDE are you using?   Rgui? RStudio?  Are you using a package-creating `package` ?   Writing the manual pages is not difficult, and  for example `skeleton` sets up the template very nicely

Comment: I think this is because the documentation template files that get set up contain text that is outside the fields. Mostly, there comments to help you. You can find these files in the `man/` root level directory. You can either edit them manually using guidance from https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html, or use an R package like _roxygen_. Neither approach is right or wrong. It's just down to personal preference. You'll find more online guidance for the _roxygen_ way.

Answer (score 1):

You should not write the manual pages yourself.   You should use `roxygen` code to write the manual elements in your function R files, then use `devtools::document()` to generate the manual pages.   See here for examples: https://keithmcnulty.github.io/r_package_training/index.html#1

Comment: `roxygen` is a good tool,  but the templates created with various R packages designed to simplify the construction of not only man but also the  NAMESPACE, DESCRIPTION, etc files work well too.

Comment: I agree with Carl. `package.skeleton()` + the R extensions guide is a good place to start learning.

Comment: Can you please explain me why shouldn't I ? I mean what are exactly disadvantages of that approach ?

Comment: Rather than give my opinion I'll quote from Hadley Wickham's book on R packages which I highly recommend:  http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/man.html

[roxygen2] has a number of advantages over writing .Rd files by hand:

Code and documentation are intermingled so that when you modify your code, you’re reminded to also update your documentation.

Roxygen2 dynamically inspects the objects that it documents, so you can skip some boilerplate that you’d otherwise need to write by hand.

It abstracts over the differences in documenting different types of objects, so you need to learn fewer details.